# Как в php передаются ресурсы, по ссылке или по значению?

Tags: php

Как в php передаются ресурсы (один из 8-ми типов данных), по ссылке или по значению?

Есть ли это в документации?

Comment: а взять и проверить? )

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: @Invision Примера нет, скорее тут теория. Но, я буду рад если вы приведете пример. Мне был адресован вопрос: в php 8 типов данных, какие из них передаются по значению, какие по ссылке? Мой ответ был - объекты передаются по ссылке, остальные по значению. На что мне был задан вопрос - а как передаются ресурсы? Я Подозреваю что это зависит от типа ресурса..

Comment: php 8 не существует

Comment: @Invision Речь о 8-ми типах данных)))

Answer (score 1):

Resource это специальная переменная, содержащая ссылку на внешний ресурс

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.resource.php

Comment: Это значит, что вопрос не корректный? Как следовало бы на него ответить?

Comment: Корректный, переменная со ссылкой на ресурс передается по ссылке

Comment: Всегда так, для всех ресурсов? Плюсанул, но лучшим пометить не могу. Чтобы ответ был полным, хотелось бы примеров и аргументации.